# Retrieve results of running query with invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

I have this script which I can use to create logins and assign sysadmin to support group.
It's not perfect, but it works.

However the problem is I am not receiving any feedback from running it. I'd need to later check if login was successfully created, which kind of defeats the purpose of it.

Is there any simple way to print message from sql whether action succeeded?
csv file look like this:

name, env

server1, prd

server2, qas

```
$servers = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\servers.csv'

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $seperate = $server.name.split('\')
    $serverName = $seperate[0]
    $instanceName = $seperate[1]
    $eServAccount = 'domain\srv-'+$serverName+''
    $eServAccountLogin = '[domain\srv-'+$serverName+']'

    if($server.env -eq 'PRD') {
        $suppGrp = 'domain\DBA PRD'
        }
    elseif($server.env -eq 'QAS') {
        $suppGrp = 'domain\DBA QAS'
        }
    elseif($server.env -eq 'DEV') {
        $suppGrp = 'domain\DBA DEV'
        }

$suppGrpLogin = '['+$suppGrp+']'
$queryString = "
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins 
    WHERE name = '$eServAccount')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN $eServAccountLogin FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
    
End

IF EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins 
    WHERE name = '$eServAccount') AND 
        (SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ( 'sysadmin', '$eServAccount')) = 0
BEGIN
    ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER $eServAccountLogin
END
   
    
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins 
    WHERE name = '$suppGrp')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN $suppGrpLogin FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
    
End

IF EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins 
    WHERE name = '$suppGrp') AND 
        (SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ( 'sysadmin', '$suppGrp')) = 0
BEGIN
    ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER $suppGrpLogin
END
"    
    
    
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server.name -Database master -Query $queryString

}
```

Answer (score 0):

with invoke-sqlcmd you can use the parameter -OutputSqlErrors $true to report errors, if you don't have errors it should be successful ;-)